# Twitter Search Widget only shows most recent tweets

Tags: twitter

We are attempting to use the Twitter Search Widget in our website: [Twitter widget](https://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_search)

However, it only seems to display the most recent tweets.

For example, if using the following search query, we only get back 4 results posted in the last 25 hours, but none older: from:CorkBoston since:2010-01-01

Is this a limitation? I don't see it in any of the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is their limitation:

- `The Search API is not complete index of all Tweets, but instead an index of recent Tweets. At the moment that index includes between 6-9 days of Tweets.`
- `You cannot use the Search API to find Tweets older than about a week.`

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search